# Failed to invoke procedure `ga.timetree.now`: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.graphaware.module.timetree.SingleTimeTree

Tags: neo4j, graphaware

I am unable to run

```
CALL ga.timetree.now({})
```

It fails with a subj error. My neo4j.conf includes the following:

```
dbms.unmanaged_extension_classes=com.graphaware.server=/graphaware
com.graphaware.runtime.enabled=true
com.graphaware.module.TT.1=com.graphaware.module.timetree.module.TimeTreeModuleBootstrapper
```

Iam using `neo4j 3.4.12` with `grapaware-server-all.3.4.9.52` and `timetree-3.4.9.52.28` built from repositories and put into `/plugins` directory.

Could anyone help me with what i am missing ?

Comment: The very first attempt to run the procedure causes 
```Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `ga.timetree.now`: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.graphaware.common.log.LoggerFactory```

Answer (score 0):

The Graphaware (and TimeTree) plugins are only available to the Community edition of Neo4j. If you are using Neo4j Desktop, you are probably running the Enterprise edition (with a free developer license). You can check that in Neo4j Desktop by clicking the ellipses on the database instance, clicking "Manage", and then looking at the version under "Details".