# Neo4J Plugin Graphaware TimeTree: Problems when calling ga.timetree

Tags: neo4j, graphaware

I am using NEO4J in version 4.2.1 (community edition). I wanted to use the plugin TimeTree from Graphaware and copied

```
graphaware-server-community-4.2.0.58.jar
timetree-3.5.14.55.29.jar
```

in the plugin folder. I also added

```
ga.timetree.* to dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted
```

in the config and restartet the neo4j-server.
When I start to do a test e.g. with

```
 CALL ga.timetree.single({time: 1463659567468})
```

I always run into the error

```
Failed to invoke procedure `ga.timetree.single`: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.graphdb.event.TransactionEventHandler
```

Searching the web I only found one explanation which points to [Failed to invoke procedure `ga.timetree.now`: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.graphaware.module.timetree.SingleTimeTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61591876/failed-to-invoke-procedure-ga-timetree-now-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-co) which explains to use the community edition of Neo4j instead of the Enterprise edition. I checked twice and I am pretty sure I run the community edition (Neo4j Server version: 4.2.1 (community)).

Does anyone has an idea what I need to change to get it running?

Thanks
Balael

Comment: The plugin is not yet compatible with Neo4j 4.2, it will be in the beginning of the year.

Comment: Thank you! I will post this as an answer to close the question.

Comment: Just for clarification: Version 4.1x of Neo4J has the same issues, seems, the current plugin timetree-3.5.14.55.29 is only compatible with versions <= 3.5 of Neo4J?

Answer (score 0):

Comment by Christophe: The plugin is not yet compatible with Neo4j 4.2, it will be in the beginning of the year. –